# How can I reset my SGH-999?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, factory-reset, reboot, recovery-mode, device-firmware

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 (SGH-999) and am trying to do a hard reset. Somewhere along the line, things got a bit messed up. It keeps telling me I have a firmware update, and when I click `start` to start the update, the phone reboots and does not boot back up. To restart it, I remove the battery and then restart, but at the top it says "Recovery Booting" in blue text.

So then I shut down (remove battery) and restart in flash mode. Then when I restart, it boots up telling me that the upgrade failed.

So now, I want to completely reset my phone, but am unable to do so. I've tried all of the methods listed at http://www.hard-reset.com/samsung-galaxy-s3-hard-reset.html and no success, it continues to boot into the `Samsung Galaxy SIII` screen with the blue text at the top.

Any ideas?